# java swing events

Tags: java, swing

I want when I enter a button, text to appear in the console. How can I combine the methods there is my comfusing, can someone explain and give example.

Comment: Why don't you read a tutorial? The answer is fairly elementary and extremely easy to find in every book and Swing tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Button1");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button1 was Clicked!");

        }
    });

    // add button to a container
```

Comment: tnx to all, now i understood the main way to work with them :)

Comment: Note that it is 'unusual' to have a GUI that prints anything intended for the user on the console.  Why not have a button and a `JTextField` or `JTextArea` to write the output to?

Answer (score 0):

Use a MouseListener. For example:

```
JComponent button = new JButton();
component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse entered the button");
    }
});
```

MouseAdapter is a special MouseListener that has default empty implementations of all the other methods that the MouseListener provides, so you don't have to override them. You may want to look at the Javadoc for MouseAdapter, MouseListener, and MouseEvent.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood your question--I assumed that you wanted to know whether the cursor entered the button. If you wnt to know if the button's been clicked, Bala R's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ActionListener` to the button. In the `actionPerformed()` method print text on the console or whatever else you want.